# matlab: Adding square brackets to all individual numerical values within cell arrays

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell, square-bracket

I wish to add a cell array (Ma) into another cell array. However both needs to be of the same format (individual cells in square brackets).

For instance I have an array..

> > Ma{1,:}.'

ans =

Columns 1 through 8

```
'83.6'    '85.2'    '91'    '87.9'    '91.8'    '86.3'    '90.6'    '90.2'
```

How do i add square brackets to all the numerical values of very individual cells?

Below is what i wish to obtain, it is also a 1x8 cell.

```
ans =[83.6]    [85.2]    [91]    [87.9]    [91.8]    [86.3]    [90.6]    [90.2]
```

Comment: The way you show it now, `Ma{1,:}.'` is a cell array of strings, and you want to obtain a cell array of doubles (or any other numerical type). Is that correct?

Comment: Hi i understand that they are strings and i wish to convert them into numerical values. However, what i am stuck with, is to add square brackets to every single values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cell values are strings (you can tell by the quote marks `'` surrounding the values).  You wish to convert them to numerical values ("add square brrckets around them" as you put it).

To convert string to double you can use [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) command:

```
M = str2double( M{1,:} );
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to go back to my original array to add in the square brackets, which is quite a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the square brackets yourself. This just means that it is a numerical value in a cell.

In order to achieve this you should do the following, using both the [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) as [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) functions:

```
newM = num2cell(str2double(Ma{1,:}))
```